# How can I temporarily block UIScrollView scrolling while handling a UIPanGestureRecognizer event on its parent view?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a custom presentation that allows a presented controller to be dragged up and down. The thing is, if that controller has a `UIScrollView` inside of it, I want to *only* allow scrolling of the `UIScrollView` if the controller is "locked" in place, ie. at maximum or minimum Y value that I have set.

Another stipulation is that any presented controller does not have to set any delegates on the `UIScrollView` views it might have. I want the presented controller to require no knowledge of the presentation method so that presentation can be a drop-in solution.

I've been trying to make this work for close to a week. I've poured through every page of the [Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW1) and can't seem to find a good solution for making the two play nice. No matter what, my `UIScrollView` is *always* first (because it's at the top), so my method of "locking" the `UIScrollView` when it shouldn't be able to scroll is jarringly imperfect.

I have identified three major solutions:

1. **Solution**: All gesture recognizers work simultaneously. **Problem**: This allows the `UIScrollView` to scroll while the controller is panning.
2. **Solution**: `UIScrollView` is disabled until the gesture event on the presentation controller ends. **Problem**: This is really jarring, requiring the user to lift their finger and place it down again to scroll the inside view.
3. **Solution**: `UIScrollView` is locked in place as *soon* as it can be and the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the presentation controller controls this state. **Problem**: Because the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` fires *second*, the `UIScrollView` can actually move around before it can be locked in place.

There's a lot going on here and a lot I've tried, I'm at the end of my rope at this point. If someone can help me find a solution for this, I would be_so_ appreciative.

[My GitHub Project - Draggable Modal](https://github.com/bdrelling/Sandbox-iOS/tree/master/DraggableModal)

If anyone understands my problem and can add clarity to the above, please don't be afraid to help me edit my question. It's a complex problem, so finding the balance between clarity and brevity is really hard.